# Does deleting an azure blueprint assignment also delete the resources?

Tags: azure, azure-blueprints

I'm not too familiar with azure blueprints but I have a task to update an existing blueprint definition. This involves adding a couple of artifacts and a new resource group. I have a couple of questions about this process:

1. If the blueprint definition is updated as a result, does it affect the existing blueprint assignments?
2. The [azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/) strictly talks about blueprints and does not mention the affect on resources as a result of updates, is there a risk in destroying resources as a result of updating a blueprint?

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/how-to/update-existing-assignments#rules-for-updating-assignment) provides answers to your questions -

- If the parameters of the policy assignment are changed, the existing assignment is updated.
- If the definition of the policy assignment is changed, a new policy assignment is created. Policy assignments previously deployed are left in place.
- If the policy assignment artifact is removed from the blueprint, deployed policy assignments are left in place.